# Possible bug / bad feature? "Moved to chat" comment may be deleted

Tags: support, status-completed

One of my answers got some comments, and some of the commenters and me were having an exchange of ideas.

I (and some commenters) realized that it should be moved to chat, so I did click on the link.

The issue is that I returned to the question and, while trying to do some cleanup, accidentally deleted the (automatically generated) comment that linked to the chat room. Now the chat room is unreachable (if it still exists at all) and I no longer have the option to create a new chat room.

I think the comment with the link to the chat room should not be deletable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted comments aren't really deleted. They can still be seen by moderators. If you tell us which answer you are talking about I can repost the continue-in-chat comment.

Regarding the feature-request to make continue-in-chat comments undeletable or repostable after being deleted: That would be a technical change which would apply to all stackexchange sites equally, so you might want to ask about it on [the general meta stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The comment was in this answer, thank you: http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14400/6259

Comment: @SJuan76 finished.